# How can I get previous month name using `switch`?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

```js
var month_name;
switch(new Date().getMonth()) {
    case 0 :
        month_name = "January";
    break;
    case 1 :
        month_name = "February";
    break;
    case 2 :
        month_name = "March";
    break;
    case 3 :
        month_name = "April";
    break;
    case 4 :
        month_name = "May";
    break;
    case 5 :
        month_name = "June";
    break;
    case 6 :
        month_name = "July";
    break;
    case 7 :
        month_name = "October";
    break;
    case 8 :
        month_name = "September";
    break;
    case 9 :
        month_name = "October";
    break;
    case 10 :
        month_name = "November";
    break;
    case 11 :
        month_name = "December";
    break;
}
console.log(month_name - 1);
```

The result of this code is `NaN`.

I am trying to get to get previous month name, but the result is not a number.

How to get name of previous month?

Comment: Why are you adding `-1` to that?

Comment: I have a calendar work and i try to get yesterday name of day of week , i dont know how to do that just was trying

Comment: for example today is thursday im trying to get wednesday

Comment: @WebDev and updated again to make functions

Answer (score 0):

Not clear why you would need a switch

To get the name of months you can do

```js
const months = ["January", "Febtruary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "Dececember"];
const getMonthName = offset => { 
  let d = new Date();
  d.setHours(15, 0, 0, 0); // normalise
  return months[d.getMonth()+offset];
};  
const prevMonth = getMonthName(-1);
const thisMonth = getMonthName(0);
const nextMonth =getMonthName(+1)
console.log("\n",
"Last month was", prevMonth,"\n",
"This month is", thisMonth,"\n",
"Next month will be", nextMonth
)
```

Alternatively use [intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)

```js
const getMonth = offset => { 
  let d = new Date(); 
  d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth()+offset,15,15, 0, 0, 0); // normalise to mid month at 3pm
  return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { month: 'long' }).format(d)
};

const lastMonth = getMonth(-1);
const thisMonth = getMonth(0);
const nextMonth = getMonth(+1);

console.log("\n",
"Previous month was",lastMonth,"\n",
"This month is",thisMonth,"\n",
"Next month will be",nextMonth,"\n",
)
```

To get yesterday

```js
const getDayName = offset => {
    let d = new Date();
    d.setHours(15, 0, 0, 0); // normalise
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + offset);
    return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {weekday: 'long' }).format(d);
 };

console.log("\n",
"Yesterday was", getDayName(-1),"\n",
"Today is", getDayName(0),"\n",
"Tomorrow will be", getDayName(1),"\n"
)
```

If you insist on switch. deduct the month first:

```js
const getMonthName = offset => {
  let d = new Date(), month_name;
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth()+offset); // this will wrap to 12 from January
  switch (d.getMonth()) {
    case 0:  return "January";
    case 1:  return "February";
    case 2:  return "March";  
    case 3:  return "April";  
    case 4:  return "May";    
    case 5:  return "June";   
    case 6:  return "July";   
    case 7:  return "October";
    case 8:  return "September";
    case 9:  return "October";
    case 10: return "November"; 
    case 11: return "December"; 
  }
}
console.log("\n",
"Last month",getMonthName(-1),"\n",
"This month",getMonthName(0),"\n",
"Next month",getMonthName(1),"\n"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `switch` statement to:

```
 switch(new Date().getMonth() - 1) {
```

and add `case -1 :` to December.

```js
var month_name;
switch(new Date().getMonth() - 1) {
    case 0 :
        month_name = "January";
    break;
    case 1 :
        month_name = "February";
    break;
    case 2 :
        month_name = "March";
    break;
    case 3 :
        month_name = "April";
    break;
    case 4 :
        month_name = "May";
    break;
    case 5 :
        month_name = "June";
    break;
    case 6 :
        month_name = "July";
    break;
    case 7 :
        month_name = "October";
    break;
    case 8 :
        month_name = "September";
    break;
    case 9 :
        month_name = "October";
    break;
    case 10 :
        month_name = "November";
    break;
    case 11 :
    case -1 :
        month_name = "December";
    break;
}
console.log(month_name);
```

Comment: No this isnt what im searching , im dont want to change the switch statement becuase i need current name of month , next and previous

Comment: Then add `case 12:` to January. `getMonth()` returns a number between 0 and 11, so one month either side gives a range of -1 to +12. If you want more months than this, you will need modular arithmetic, or use @mplungjan's first method, which is more standard.